# How do we cast context to fragment reference?

Tags: android, android-fragments, casting

I have a class 'Common' and a fragment 'FragmentTest'. The 'Common.java' is a general class that have some common functions for other activities..Those functions are accessed by context of each activities.. And here  I am passing the *fragment's context* to a function in that class. I am doing like this

In Fragment :-

```
 Common commonObj = new Common();
 commonObj.myfunction(this.getActivity(),"Do you want to Update ?");
```

And in Class after some operation  i'm trying to return back to fragment class.Like this 
 :-

```
public void myfunction(Context context , String str){    
   //....//
  if(context.getClass().isInstance(FragmentTest.class)){
      **FragmentTest mContext = (FragmentTest)context;**
      mContext.FunctionInFragment();
  }
}
```

But i have error in this..Because i cannot cast the context to fragment reference.
Somebody please help..

Comment: Is `FragmentTest` a `Fragment` or a `FragmentActivity`? They aren't the same thing, and you can't cast a `Context` to a `Fragment`, since a `Fragment` is not a `Context`.

Comment: It is a Fragment

Comment: the fragment is using inside an Activity class

Comment: OK, well, you can't do that, since a `Fragment` is not a `Context`.

Comment: commonObj.myfunction(this.getActivity(),"Do you want to Update ?");    using this we can pass it right? then why we can't get the reference back??

Comment: You're not passing the `Fragment` there. You're passing the `Activity` it's in. If you want to pass the `Fragment`, remove `getActivity()`, and change your method's parameter type, or overload the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you can't cast a `Context` to a `Fragment` as `Fragment` doesn't extend `Context`.  `Activity` does extend `Context` which is why when you do this from an Activity what you are trying works.

I'd suggest ideally that the methods in your `Common` class should be totally unaware of the existence of your `Fragment`.  This way they are not 'coupled' together.  To achieve this you can use a callback interface.

Create an `interface` as follows:

```
public interface Callback<T> {

    onNext(T result);
}
```

Then you can change your method in `Common` to the following:

```
public void myfunction(Callback<Void> callback , String str){    

    //....//
    callback.onNext(null);
}
```

Then when you call the method in `Common` from the `Fragment` you would do it like this:

```
Common commonObj = new Common();
commonObj.myfunction(
    new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Void result) {
            functionInFragment();
        }
    },
    "Do you want to Update ?"
);
```

If you needed to send data back to the function then you can change the return type of the callback.  For instance if you wanted to pass back a string you would use `Callback<String>` and then the method in the original call would look like this:

```
new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(String result) {

    }
}
```

And in your `Common` class you would call it like this:

```
public void myfunction(Callback<String> callback , String str){    

    //....//
    String result = "Hello from common";
    callback.onNext(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public void myfunction(BaseFragment fragment, String str){ 
  //....//
  if(fragment.getClass().isInstance(FragmentTest.class)){
      FragmentTest fr = (FragmentTest) fragment;
      fr.FunctionInFragment();
  }
}
```

i.e. using some base fragment(BaseFragment) and inherit from it.