# Calling notifyItemChanged() on a RecyclerView.Adapter from another class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `RecyclerView` in `AdapterActivity`. After clicking on any of its items, I update that item using my `AlertDialogShow#UpdateStudent()` method. My problem is that I can not refresh the `Adapter` inside the `UpdateStudent()` method using `notifyItemChanged()`.

How can I refresh the `Adapter` from another class that does not have direct access to the `Adapter`?

In the `AdapterActivity` with the `RecyclerView`:

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialogShow show =
                new AlertDialogShow(context, database, studentData, performanceData);
            show.UpdateStudent(studentName, studentId, classId, position);
        }
    }
}
```

The `AlertDialogShow` class:

```
public class AlertDialogShow {

    Context context;
    DatabaseHandler database;
    List<StudentTable> studentData;

    public AlertDialogShow(Context context, DatabaseHandler database,
                           List<StudentTable> studentData , List<PerformanceTable> performanceData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.database = database;
        this.studentData = studentData;
        this.performanceData = performanceData;
    }

    public AlertDialog UpdateStudent(final String studentName, final String studentId, 
                                     final int classId , final int position) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        View viewLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                                        .inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_edit_class_or_student , null);
        dialog.setView(viewLayout);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();

        Button editStudent_btn = (Button)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_btn_EditClassStudent_Edit);

        editStudent_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    database.UpdateStudentDatabase(classId , studentId_new , studentId, studentName_new);

                    StudentTable studentTable = studentData.get(position);
                    studentTable.setStudentName(studentName_new);
                    studentTable.setStudentId(studentId_new);
                    studentData.set(position , studentTable);
                    //notifyItemChanged(position); <-- cannot define this line
                }
            }
        );

        return alertDialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: may be you can use handler for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating `RecyclerView` adapter can only be done in adapter itself or through adapters instance in your `Activity`. To reach those methods you need to use interfaces like so:

```
public class AlertDialogShow {

    public interface OnItemChange {
        void notifyAdapter(int position);
    }

    private OnItemChange listener;

    public AlertDialogShow(...) {
        this.listener = (MyActivity)context;
    }
}
```

Then write an implementation for OnItemChange interface in your `Activity` like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends ... implements AlertDialogShow.OnItemChange {

    @Override 
    public void notifyAdapter(int position) {
        // Notify your adapter item change here
        // e.g.: adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

Then you can use `OnItemChange` listener in your `AlertDialogShow` class like so:

```
this.listener.notifyAdapter(position);
```

This will call `notifyAdapter(int position)` method in your `Activity` and execute code that you have written there.

---

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help but i cant define `(MyActivity)context;` in AlertDialogShow Constructor

Comment: i want to pass OnItemChange  to Adapter Activity

Comment: I understand what you want to do. Why cannot you define `(MyActivity)context` in `AlertDialogShow` constructor? Does it produce some kind of error? If you can provide error logs.

Comment: i try use (RecyclerViewAdapter)context but This error shows `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'com.example.user.classmanager.RecyclerViewAdapter_StudentList`

Comment: and if i use (MyActivity)context this error shows `Required:
com.example.user.classmanager.AlertDialogShow.OnItemChange`

Comment: Your `Activity` has to implement `AlertDialogShow.OnItemChange` or else context cannot be cast to `Activity`.

Comment: i did it successful , now how can i send a String with Position(for update my List)

Comment: Use a `listener` as your communication tool between your adapter and `AlertDialogShow` like this: `this.listener.notifyAdapter(position);`

Comment: Happy to help. Answer is correct, you should accept it :)

Comment: hey friend Can i Ask You one more Question? @Tomas Jablonskis

Comment: Go ahead. @NimaKhalili

Comment: i found new peroblem , How can I reference(Object interface) to a Fragment instead of  Activity ?(in Constructor AlertDialogShow)

Comment: You want to use Fragment as a Context like this? `(MyFragment)context;`?

Comment: yes i use `(SecondTab)context;` but have this error `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.content.Context' to 'com.example.user.classmanager.SecondTab` . SecondTab is My Fragment Tab

Comment: You cannot cast `Context` to `Fragment`, read this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568311/how-do-we-cast-context-to-fragment-reference

Comment: Thank You , This post did not help me, but I found one way @Tomas Jablonskis