# This listener for sending data from activity to recyclerview is not working

Tags: android, listener

I want to send information back to the recyclerview to update the view but the listener is not working. I have this message at compiler "error: cannot find symbol variable listener"

DoneByDefault is the class that sends the data back to the recyclerview

```
public class DoneByDefault extends AppCompatActivity {
```

……..

```
public interface onItemChange{
    void notifyAdapter(int position,BatchObject payload);
}

private onItemChange listener;

public DoneByDefault(Context context){
    this.listener=(SelectBatchStep)context;
}

public DoneByDefault(){

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_done_by_default);
    xpayload=new BatchObject();
    …….
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ……
            xpayload.setmStep_Answer(xanswer);
            xpayload.setmStep_Comments(xcomments);
            xpayload.setmStep_DoneBy(user_doneby);
            xpayload.setmStep_Done_Date(dateString);
            xpayload.setmStep_Id(stepid);
            xpayload.setmbatch_No(batchnumber);
            xpayload.setmStep_No(stepnumber);
            xpayload.setmStep_Question_Type(stepquestiontype);
            xpayload.setmStep_Question(stepquestion);
            Error here: this.listener.notifyAdapter(xposition,xpayload);

            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

SelectBatchStep is the class with the recycler

```
public class SelectBatchStep extends AppCompatActivity implements DoneByDefault.onItemChange{

……

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_batch_step);
    ….
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mAdapter=new SelectBatchStepAdapter(this, batchObjectList, rBatch_No, ruser, document_no);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    ……

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ……

@Override
public void notifyAdapter(int position,BatchObject payload){

    batchObjectList.set(position,payload);
    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Comment: Remove `this.` from the beginning of that line. Also, though the posted code is incomplete, what I assume you're attempting to do is not going to work.

Comment: Removing "this" causes the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.innovative_solutions.batchrecord.DoneByDefault$onItemChange.notifyAdapter(int, com.innovative_solutions.batchrecord.BatchObject)' on a null object reference
        at com.innovative_solutions.batchrecord.DoneByDefault$1.onClick(DoneByDefault.java:130)

Comment: I am trying to do what was suggested in this post: "
Updating RecyclerView adapter can only be done in adapter itself or through adapters instance in your Activity. To reach those methods you need to use interfaces"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708825/how-to-use-notifyitemchanged-in-another-activity

Comment: That's because you only assign `listener` in the constructor you've defined there, but that is never used. It wouldn't work, anyway, because the `DoneByDefault` instance you would create by invoking that constructor would not be a valid `Activity` instance. The example you've linked is updating from an `AlertDialog`, not a separate `Activity` – even though they call it an `Activity`, mistakenly – so it's not really applicable to your setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Could you suggest a way to achieve this request?

Answer (score 0):

1.you must be using Intent when activity send data to activity
 2.you will be using onActivityResult or Broadcast Receiver！！！

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more. I don't understand what you are trying to tell

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

       BatchObject batchObject =new BatchObject();
        batchObject .setmStep_Answer(xanswer);
        batchObject .setmStep_Comments(xcomments);
        batchObject .setmStep_DoneBy(user_doneby);
       ....
        this.listener.notifyAdapter(xposition,batchObject );

        finish();
    }
```